# Jmeter extract a value using BeanShell PostProcessor

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter, beanshell

I want to extract b from the following response and use it as a parameter for a new request, can you help me?

Response:

```
[[
{"a": { "x": "123", "y": "456", "z": "789" }, "p": ["111"], "q": "222"},
"b"
]]
```

Comment: I suggest using JSON path extractor post processor instead of custom code. It's included with JMeter 3.0 (http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) or can be installed as plug-in in earlier versions (https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JSONPathExtractor/)

Comment: can you suggest me the right "JSONPath Expression"? I have already "jp@gc - JSON Path Extractor" post processor plugin.

Comment: in that response I have double brackets (jsonarray..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need for Beanshell here.

Use JMeter 3.0 [JSON Path Post Processor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) with following JSON Path Expression:

> $..[1]

See this plan:

[image]

Syntax is described here:

- http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/